# React Native - external style not working the same as inline

Tags: react-native

I am trying to downsize image according to screen width. However when I try to remove inline it suddenly stops to work. I don't see the mistake.

This works:

```
export default class App extends Component<Props> {
    render() {
        return (
            <ImageBackground style={{
                flex: 1,
                width: deviceWidth,
                height: (deviceWidth / 3) * 2,
                alignSelf: 'center'
            }} source={require('./img/space.jpeg')}>
                <Text style={styles.something}>Neco</Text>
            </ImageBackground>
        );
    }
}

const deviceWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    something: {
        fontSize: 40,
        color: 'red'
    }
});
```

[working example picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ox7zd.png)

This breaks:

```
...
<ImageBackground style={styles.what} source={require('./img/space.jpeg')}> 
    <Text style={styles.something}>Neco</Text>
</ImageBackground>
...
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    what: {
        flex: 1,
        width: deviceWidth,
        height: (deviceWidth / 3) * 2,
        alignSelf: 'center'
    },
    something: {
        fontSize: 40,
        color: 'red'
    }
});
```

[broken example picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUJgU.png)

Comment: Check your package runner for error.

Comment: After running `react-native run-android`, there are no errors in the console, where it was run, no in the Metro Bundler window and no in Chrome developer tools console.

Comment: @OliverTušla Could you please show all of the code. In the bottom example you don't show the entire render() function and `const deviceWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width;` is also missing. Is it there?

Comment: Can you check with height hardcoded to some value?

Comment: @Andru There has been no change to the surrounding code. However, I found out that it works when I remove `flex`, then it works.

Comment: @AshwinMothilal The same applies, works only without `flex`.

Comment: It means the deviceWidth is not available when the Stylesheet loads this style. If you want you can try it inspecting with react-devtools.

Comment: @AshwinMothilal No, it is available. Those values just don't take any effect. Consider those 4 with outlined and inlined styles. https://imgur.com/a/r93Cs4Z

Comment: When outlined, the dimensions don't propagate to nested Image (generated by ImageBackground component).